# Using springboot in a kotlin environment, writing controller to use kotlin will cause transaction failures?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, transactions

I added @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class) in controller file,and add @EnableTransactionManagement in main application.

Using java transactions does work, but writing controller transactions in kotlin does not work.

Transactions depend on aop,How do I use transactions in kotlin?

I don't want to control the transaction manually with a try catch ,
how to fix this problems?

Comment: This post may need a little more specifics, to give it some clarity.

Comment: Your question is more spring boot aop related than kotlin related, without error log, it's difficult to guess why kotlin would interfere in this situation.